# Split array by more than one value

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
'(1 and 2 and 3) or 4 and 5'
```

It should be constructed from

```
array =[1 ,2 ,3,4,5 '(', ')', '', 'and', 'or', 'AND', 'OR', ' '];
```

it can use any combination but should be from this array only.

I have tried

```
const arr1 = value.trim().split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i += 1) {
    if (!arryOfContaining.includes(arr1[i])) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
```

But the problem is how to split the string. it will have always space in between words but not with brackets. Any help?

Comment: `.split` accepts regular expressions, if that helps

Comment: Thanks @JeremyThille used expression /(?=[)\s]|\b|[(\s])/ to split.